# SDL2 main ticking system(openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm new in SDL2, and cannot find any ticking system in SDL2 c++.

I wanna get something like that:

```
bool running = true;
while(running)
{
    render(); //my own created render void
    // some kind of FPS optimalization with redraw
    // here
}
```

Comment: where is this ticking needed then? do you want to measure elapsed time to perform some optimization? Some more code would be nice.

Comment: Just want to make a small game so optimalized about 60 FPS.

Comment: maybe this will help [SDL_GetTicks](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryTimer%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruc%29%7C%28SGFunctionst%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you want to run your render loop at a whole multiple of the display refresh period. Since after a call to `SwapBuffers` the next drawing OpenGL call will block until the actual swap got executed this automatically limits you to the display refresh frequency. No need to implement a custom timing scheme.

Only if you disabled V-Sync in the graphics drivers you'll may run faster than the display refresh.